# Getting NullPointerException while calling interface StationDao method through StationService class which has implemention in StationDaoImpl class

Tags: java, interface

my code is like

```
public class StationService 
{
private  StationDao stationDao;

public StationService(StationDao stationDao) {
     this.stationDao = stationDao;
}

public void insertData(PoliceStationBeans beans) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("In Implementation:"+beans.getArea()+""+beans.getUserName()
            +""+beans.getPassword()+""+beans.getEmail());

     stationDao.insertData(beans); //Getting Error Here
}
}
```

How to resolve this error
I reffered this question [Can i call a method which is inside an interface without implementing the interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554661/can-i-call-a-method-which-is-inside-an-interface-without-implementing-the-interf)

Comment: You are either constructing `StationService` with a null `StationDao`; or you are somehow setting `stationDao` to null post construction; or the NPE actually occurs inside the implementation of `StationDao.insertData`.

Comment: while calling insertData(beans) method